# Finding the mistake(s) within this "proof" of NP being closed for complement

Tags: complexity-theory, closure-properties, np, co-np

For my classes in theoretical computer science the following proof must be shown to be wrong. However, this is the first time I am attempting myself at this topic, so I would be thankful for some help:

> *Lemma*:
>
> If $L \in NP $, then $ \bar{L} \in NP $
>
> *Proof*:
>
> - Let N be a non-deterministic Turing machine, which accepts L in polynomial time.
> - Swap all final states of $N$ with non-final states and vice-versa.
> - This new Turing machine $N'$ does now accept $\bar{L}$ in polynomial time.
>
> Therefore $\bar{L} \in NP$

I have doubts that simply swapping non-final and final states within $N$ will produce a $N'$ with the proposed properties, but how can I show this?

Comment: This may be easier to think about if you imagine that $N$ first makes all of its non-deterministic choices and then does something deterministic.

Comment: [Closely related question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/55239/98).

Comment: Neither does the technique work for automata as simple as [nondeterministic finite state](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/38041/when-states-that-are-not-accepting-states-become-accepting-states-in-nfa-what-h) automata.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to show that swapping final and non-final states doesn't complement the language accepted by an NTM, e.g., by showing that, for at least one NTM $N$ (which you can construct to have whatever properties you need), there is a  string that is accepted by both $N$ and $N'$, or rejected by both.

Comment: How should I go about starting an argument like this? I neither have a precise definition of $N$ nor $L$, and since $N$ is nondeterminisitic I find it hard to understand how something like this would be stated.

Comment: It's enough to do it for a *particular* $L$ and a *particular* $N$.